# lenovo thinkpad t450s hardware (screen and performance) issue

Tags: laptop, performance, hardware-failure, thinkpad

I have an issue with Lenovo t450s laptop, and I'll describe it next.

Under Windows 10 (booted from SSD) I have image flickering near animated and moving objects. I can barely load any application due to low performance. Every time I try to start a Web Browser (any) it will load and then disappear (stop working). What have I done:

- Used different test from the load menu to test memory, ssd, and other
  components. Everything was fine;
- Used memtest bootable application to test RAM. No problem has been
  found;
- Loaded bootable linux (2-3 different distributives). They had also
  problem with opening even terminal GUI client (also other programs,
  e.g. web browser). Every time I was thrown on the logging menu. Some
  times mouse didn't work for some time.

From BIOS I can easily configure and navigate. But any OS will not work properly.

It's not a software issue by my understanding. But I have a hard time defining where the problem might come from (can the CPU be partially damaged, and some parts of it work erroneously?)

Comment: Has it been dropped or had a sudden physical shock? Or been made wet by liquids? Have you ever seen it working properly? I'm thinking damaged motherboard (cracked?) or components on motherboard damaged or detached.

Comment: you got warranty? [RMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_merchandise_authorization) asap

Comment: @Gantendo hello. No warranty, it was used one.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey hello. As far I know no. And for the first week it has not behaving in this manner. I also think some components on the motherboard. I'll verify thoroughly motherboard, but if it's some component I would probably not find it.

Comment: Possibly the seller knew it would start to go wrong after 1 weeks use. Is it the problem the same on AC power and battery?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey it's possible. Yes it's the same problem with AC (I tried it with and without).